# General probability to pass a point on a 2D grid in a drunken walk

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

A drunken person can walk only on the lattice points of a 2D plane. He starts at the origin . At any point probability of his going along any direction equal. What is the probability that he will pass a certain point (x, y).

There was a similar question on the site but it did not have any answers while the others put a restriction on the number of paths . Also I got this question only out of naive curiosity hence don't have a way to verify any answer. As the limit was of an indeterminate type, I think a definitive answer may be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polya proved in 1921 that a random walk on 2D lattice returns to the origin with probability 1 ([proof](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.095/lect2/notes.pdf)).

This implies that the walk returns to the origin $n$ times with probability 1 for any $n$. Since 1/4 of those immediately next visit the rightmost neighbor, we see that $(1,0)$ is reached $n$ times with probability 1 for any $n$. By induction, we see that $(x,y)$ is reached with probability 1 for all $(x,y)$.